# How to develop a client-server seat booking program via java socket programming?

Tags: java, sockets, client

---

I have a project to develop a **client server** application in **java**. This is to be done using **socket** programming. Our lecturer, used 2 files, the **TCPClient.java** and **TCPServer.java**, to make a connection and we typed **"Hi"** in the client and the server **displayed** that message.

I need to develop a **seat booking** application.

Any suggestions for **tutorials** or **tips** or a **book** perhaps would be nice.

---

***Many Thanks***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of logic involved in building a seat booking application compared to a simple "echo console".

I would suggest that you first write the entire application uses two "top level" classes instantiated from main - a client and a server. Have them send objects (or strings) to one another for requests and responses.

Once you have that tried and tested (and backed up!), try and replace the messages they send to one another with sockets based on the examples you saw in class or in the sample files. The java tutorial has almost all the examples you would need as well.

Once all this is done, separate the client and the server into separate mains() and get it to work with two processes.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) is how I taught myself Socket programming.  Take a look at that tutorial.  It will help you a bunch,